# Submit to external URL and redirect? Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect, form-submit

So I have this form that is submitting to Docusign for verification and secure signing. It populates PDF data from the form and that works fine.

The issue is, I want to redirect to another URL after client side validation and confirm message, but `window.location.href` is not working. (console logs and alerts work fine).

**My form is like this:**

```
<form action="https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=89-XXXXXX" method="POST" target="_blank" id="theLeaseForm" >
  .... 
</form>
```

I want to just use PHP to redirect the form on submit via `header("Location: myOtherPage.php");`.

How do I hook into that?

Also, can you tell me why Javascript `window.location` method is not working, but other JS functions run fine on submit?

**Here is my JS code: (notice the last onValid function)..**

```
$("#theLeaseForm").validVal({
    fields: {
        onInvalid: function( $form, language ) {
            $(this).addClass("invalid");
        },
        onValid: function( $form, language ) {
            $(this).addClass("valid");
        }
    }, form : {
        onInvalid: function( $fields, language ) {
            $(".errorbox").html("Please complete the fields marked in red and try again").show();
            var position = $(".errorbox").position();
            scroll(0,position.top);
                            window.location.href = 'http://www.identityseattle.com/thank-you/';
        },
        onValid: function() {
            console.log("form is successful"); //This works fine
            window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/thank-you/'; //This doesn't work
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: have you tried to a) use window.location.href?; b) Create a form pointing to your redirector php and submit such form?

Comment: We can't say why the javascript is not working without seeing your javascript. Same goes for your php `header`

Comment: You can not redirect POST data. And if you send your form to an external address, then a redirect after processing the data would have to be issued by that external site.

Comment: Added my JS code above. I'm using http://validval.frebsite.nl/ as my client side validation..

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution..

I guess a better way to ask my question would be "Javsscript redirect after target="_blank" form submit.

Anyway, a settimeout worked great..

```
onValid: function() {
 setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/thank-you/'; 
     }, 1);
 }
```